# load csv - relationships

Tags: csv, graph, load

```
social network app.
Loaded users.txt  (userid)

5
6
57355
57359
57360
```

using:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:C:/data/users.txt" AS line
create (:User { Userid:toInt(line[1]) });
```

Now, I need to create relationships (user1 follows user2)

```
userid;follower
57364;57360
57364;300946
57364;57371
57364;474039
57364;418775

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/data/rels.txt" AS line
MATCH (a:User { Userid:toInt(line[1]) })
MATCH (b:User { Userid:toInt(line[2]) })
CREATE (a)-[:FOLLOWS { roles: [line.role]}]->(b);

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/data/rels1.txt" AS line 
MATCH (a:User {    Userid:toInt(line[1]) }) 
MATCH (b:User { Userid:toInt(line[2]) }) 
CREATE (a)-[:FOLLOWS { roles: [line.role]}]->(b);

Invalid input 'T': expected whitespace, comment, '|', a length specification, a property map or ']' (line 4, column 24 (offset: 169))
"CREATE (a)-[:FOLLOWS { roles: [line.role]}]->(b);"
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I am doing a formal evaluation on Neo4j.  If someone can help answer this question before discarding this product as a prospect. Thanks.